# Django how to filter a foreign key object only with specific value

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have two tables.
Table Product

```
id | name |
```

Table Discount

```
id | product_id | is_deleted
```

Two models are:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Discount(models.Modle):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

product_id is the foreign key of product table's id, and is_deleted is a boolean field.
How can I filter all products only with is_deleted discount? Notice those two tables may be large, so `.exclude()` is not fit for this case.

Comment: Can you please share your Django models.

Comment: If a `Product` has two (or more) discounts, and only one of these has `is_deleted` set to `True`, should that be excluded, or retained?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Add model code. There's no restriction between product and discount. One product can have multiple discounts, and those discount could either is_deleted or not. I need filter out all products only with is_deleted set to true.

Comment: So if a product has two discounts, one `is_deleted` is set to `True`, and one set to `False`, does the queryset include that product, or exclude that product?

Comment: Furthermore another open question is what to do with `Product`s that do not have any discount at all.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No I don't want both these cases. Either product with one is_deleted and non is_deleted is not qualified, and product doesn't have any discount is not qualified either. I just need product only with is_deleted discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
product_ids_subquery = Discount.objects.values('product').annotate(
               deleted=(Count('product') - Count('product', filter=Q(is_deleted=True)))
            ).filter(deleted=0).values('product')

products_qs = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids_subquery)
```

we can identify that products only with is_deleted discount with the help of count after group by product. For each product,

1. calculate how many records are present in discount table. let say total_count = Count('product')
2. calculate how many records are present which is deleted. let say deleted_count = Count('product', filter=Q(is_deleted=True))
3. deleted = (total_count - deleted_count) gives you a no. which is not deleted

if deleted == 0 then you can say all mapped records are deleted

Comment: That may be a correct answer, but if product table is very large, when we try to use slice on this finally queryset, I am not sure the id__in clause will have a reasonable performance.

Comment: @TianchengLiu Here **id__in** is not IN query basically it is subquery and id is primary key So performance is not bad. If you want only product_ids then no need to  run second query. You can check raw query by printing ```print(products_qs.query)```

Comment: @joshlsullivan Code-only answers are less helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. I commented on this post within my [review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29767365) (LQA), in response the author added an explanation, which ist fine. I cannot understand your concern. Please take a look at some meta-posts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/3749896 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
products = Product.objects.filter(discount__is_deleted=True)
```